# ASP.NET Gridview is not refreshing after the delete operation

Tags: asp.net, gridview, internet-explorer-8

I have Internet Explorer 8. I have a asp:GridView in which I am showing records and image buttons to perform delete operation. I am deleting the record and calling me BindMethod on RowComand event of the gridview. The problem is that after deleting the record Internet Explorer is not refreshing. I have checked with the firefox and chrome. They are working fine.

Here is my code:
ASPX:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" CssClass="grd" EmptyDataText="No record found."
EnableViewState="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="False" 
OnRowCommand="grdView_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdView_RowDataBound" 
OnPageIndexChanging="grdView_PageIndexChanging">
     <Columns>
      bla
      bla
      bla
      bla
      bla
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
private void BindGrid()
{
     string sSQL = "select * from tableName";
     DataTable dt = DAL.getDataTable(sSQL);
     grd.DataSource = dt;
     grd.DataBind();
}

protected void grdView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
      int id= Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      //Deleting record
      bool result = DAL.DeleteRecord(id);
      if(result)
      {
          BindGrid();
      }
}
```

Please tell me why Internet Explorer is not refreshing the grid while others browsers working fine.

Comment: Lolz. Yes! that's why It is working fine in other browsers.

Comment: Do you have an `UpdatePanel`? Do you use caching?

Comment: No I don't have update panel. And I am not using Caching with my coding but I am not sure if caching is being done behind the scene.

Comment: IE may cache the page if you press the back button. Do you have any other relevant code?

Comment: No that's the relevant code only.

Comment: Try similar code in a clean project without any data connections (just faked data) and with less code as you can. Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: It is on every page. Not just with this page. So problem is being reproduced.

Comment: Can you use fiddler to check what the html being sent to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try This, grdView_`RowCommand` does not fire when your trying to Delete a row. use grdView_`RowDeleting` like below. grdView_`RowCommand` will fire only when your `GridView` is Binding

```
protected void grdView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
  int id= Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  //Deleting record
  bool result = DAL.DeleteRecord(id);
  if(result)
  {
      BindGrid();
  }
}
```